# Getting syntax error while trying to send a json object from php to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to send a json object which is created from a db query, as follows:

```
    $note_records = $DB->get_records_sql ('
                        SELECT stickyid, text, pos_x, pos_y, width, height   
                        FROM    
                        mdl_block_stickynotes');

    $rows=array();
    foreach($note_records as $note ){
        $rows[]=$note;
    }
    $data=array('notes'=> $rows);
    $data['resizable']= true;
    $data['controls']= true; 
    $data['editCallback']= "edited";
    $data['createCallback']="created";
    $data['deleteCallback']="deleted";
    $data['moveCallback']= "moved";                 
    $data['resizeCallback']= "resized";
    $note_js_data= json_encode($data);

    $this->content->text  .=
         '<div id="sticky_block_div">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pop(\''. addslashes(htmlspecialchars($root)) .'\','.$note_js_data.'>For Demo Click Here'</a>  
          </div>';
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
    SyntaxError: invalid property id
    pop('http://localhost/umoodle25',{
```

What could be the possible reason. Also, what other ways are efficient in such cases, where i need to send a json object from a php file to an external js file as a parameter of one of its function? I am very new in js and php.

Comment: for SyntaxError you have fault single quotes in `$this->content->text  .=
       '<div id="sticky_block_div">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pop(\''. addslashes(htmlspecialchars($root)) .'\','.$note_js_data.'>For Demo Click Here</a>  
          </div>'; `

Comment: Even if you fix this syntax error you will have more problems.  `json_encode` returns something like this `{"notes": ...` your attribute uses `"` as delimiter for the value wich is in conflict with the json quotes. But if you write `onclick='pop( ... )'` instead you cannot use or need to escape the other occurrence of `'`.